# MYSQL периодически падает с ошибкой (111)

Tags: mysql, linux

С недавнего времени периодически падает mysql. Конфиг стандартный, я туда не заходил и ничего не менял с момента самой установки apache2. ОС Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS «Trusty Tahr».

Ошибка такая:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

Лог пустой, как я не пытался хоть что-то там найти, но там всегда пусто. Помогает только перезагрузка, но надоело уже перезагружать постоянно VDS.

Один из сайтов на сервере на вордпрессе, если перезагружаю полностью сервер с утра, то всё работает нормально до вечера, а ближе к концу дня и перед самым падением mysql(примерно за час) сайт начинает нещадно виснуть и загружает странички по минуте.

Остальные сайты, которые на самописных движках и тоже используют эту же базу данных, работают без проблем до самого падения mysql.

В техподдержку хостинга обращался, проверили, сказали стойка работает в штатном режиме. Да и никогда не было проблем со sprinthost`ом.

[image: top]

[image: df -h]

Может кто сталкивался? Как лечить такое?

Comment: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" - это просто клиент сообщает, что не может законнектиться с мускулем, который упал. Варианты обычно какие: возможно нехватка памяти из-за неправильно установленных настроек, сначала начинает тупить из-за свопа, а потом кончается своп и сервер падает. Возможно - нехватка места на диске. Возможно есть битый файл БД, который не используется весь день, но при бэкапе всей базы вызывает краш.

Comment: Есть возможность посмотреть состояние памяти и диска, когда начинает тупить? Как минимум top запустить в линуксе. И заодно логи системы посмотреть, а не только mysql. Если были проблемы свопа, то они в системных логах будут

Comment: Не пускает на редактирование. Попробуйте tail -f лог.log Будет выдавать последние записи

Comment: А в логах mysql.err.log совсем ничего? Даже при старте?

Comment: судя по описанию, весьма похоже на то, что один (или более) из сайтов нагружает *mysqld* слишком частыми или слишком тяжеловесными запросами.

Comment: Floyat, а mysqld-процесс висит? Не может его какой-нибудь oom-killer грохать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал бэкап и полностью переустановил операционную систему с базовыми настройками. Другие решения не помогали. Да и больше двух лет сервер работал без перезагрузки ОС, много всякого мусора устанавливалось/удалялось/менялось и видимо это повлияло + отсутствие знаний тонкостей настройки и оптимизации сервера сказывалось.

Проблема исчезла и всё стало работать значительно быстрее.

Своп поставил 4гб + поднял в 2 раза все начальные параметры по mysql и php.

Теперь всё хорошо.